# Select random 50 sample from dataset in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to take 50 samples from a dataset. My dataset is diabetes from sklearn dataset. I used `diabetes_X, diabetes_y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)` method for implementation.

○ There are 442 sample points in the dataset. Take 50 samples randomly.

How can I do that?

when I use numpy choice there is an error occur : `ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional`

Comment: have a look at numpy.choice

Answer (score 2):

Use scikit-learn `resample` function. Look at [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.resample.html) if you want more info (sample with replacement, stratify, select random_state,...)

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import resample

# Create dataframe
s = """
A B C
1 5 6
5 9 2
3 8 8
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), delimiter=' ')
print(resample(df, n_samples=2))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
2  3  8  8
1  5  9  2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also done your job like this:

```
x = []
y = []
for i in np.random.choice(n_samples, 30):
    x.append(boston.data[i])
    y.append(boston.target[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use numpy or vanilla python for this job.

```
import random
import numpy as np

random.sample(data_list, num_samples)
np.random.choice(data_list, num_samples)
```

Comment: ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional

Comment: what do you feed into numpy choice as your list?